# The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. Find the sum of all the primes below two million.(I am not getting what is wrong in this code)

Tags: python-3.x

```
sum = 2
x=3
y=5000
for i in range (x,y):
    for j in range (2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            break
        elif i%j!=0 and j==i-1:
            sum += i
    if i==y-1 and y<2000000:
        x=y
        y+=5000
    else:
        continue
print(sum)
```

**I am not getting what is wrong in this code. By running this I came to know that the Last If and Else statement are not running **

Comment: why do You think they are not working? also the basic idea would be to just append to a list all prime numbers in the range and just `sum()` the list

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, there are a couple of things wrong.  First, **sum** is a python  function name and should never be used as a variable name.  It will get you into trouble in more ways than I care to think about.  Second, the last else statement is not needed, because whether the if clause above it is or is not executed executed, the for loop will be executed again. Third, I don't understand the purpose of y and the magical value 5000, unless you are trying to provide an end value for your loop.  The problem with this approach is you seem to try and extend it's range in increments of 5000.  The problem is that once the initial for loop is executed, it creates a local iterable from x to 5000, and subsequent changes to y do not affect the for loops range.

I would approach the problem differently, by creating a list of primes and then use the python sum method to add all the values.  Here is the code:

```
def sum_primes(max_prime):
    """ Return Sum of primes Less than max_prime"""
    primes = [2]
    indx_num = 3
    while primes[-1] <= max_prime:
        update = True
        for prime in primes:
            if indx_num == prime or indx_num % prime == 0:
                update = False
                break
        if update:
            primes.append(indx_num)
        indx_num += 2
    #return summ of all values except the last
    return sum(primes[:-1])
```

Executing `sum_primes(2000000)`
yields `1709600813`